# Code in Google Tag Manager does not working

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a test tasks and 2 from 3 I've done.
But this one I don't understand how and what I need to do?!

**I managed to find syntax error:
At first should be:

`...function someFunctionName() {...}`
or
`(function() {...})()`**

**...second it's anonymous function...**

**TASK:**
This script is executed in GTM and implemented in Google analytics by custom Task.
The script sends information about user behavior to Optimozg server and then to Bigquery (bq.php file processes and forwards data). Optimozg server data is coming in correctly, but the data in Google Analytics does not reach. 
What is the reason? 
How do you fix it?
Hint:
(test the code on your site instance with GTM)

```
function(){return function(tracker){if("undefined"===typeof tracker.get("BigQueryStreaming")){var f=tracker.get("sendHitTask"),h=function(){function d(c){var a=!1;try{document.createElement("img").src=e(!0)+"?"+c,a=!0}catch(k){}
return a}
function e(c){var a="https://test.optimozg.com/bq/bq-test.php";c||(a+="?tid="+encodeURIComponent(tracker.get("trackingId")));return a}
return{send:function(c){var a;if(!(a=2036>=c.length&&d(c))){a=!1;try{a=navigator.sendBeacon&&navigator.sendBeacon(e(),c)}catch(g){}}
if(!a){a=!1;var b;try{window.XMLHttpRequest&&"withCredentials" in(b=new XMLHttpRequest)&&(b.open("POST",e(),!0),b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/plain"),b.send(c),a=!0)}catch(g){}}
return a||d(c)}}}();tracker.set("sendHitTask",function(d){h.send(d.get("hitPayload"));tracker.set("BigQueryStreaming",!0)})}}}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with proper code formatting, in it's current form your code is unreadable

Comment: Is this a job interview task? And you're wrong. The code doesn't have syntax errors. It's meant to be used as a variable... As the description suggests, it's a custom task. And by google analytics they mean the tracking library, not the service. Anyhow, read more on custom tasks. It's a good senior interview question. I think I'll steal it.

Comment: @BNazaruk yes, it's a job interview task for Junior JavaScript Developer.
It's a 3rd task (with note in brackets - Advance level).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why JS devs should know anything about GTM. They typically don't go there.
But yes, to understand how to use the given code properly, just read this article: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/customtask-the-guide/ it describes what custom tasks are and how to use them.

Ok, so first make a GTM account. Deploy the GTM code on your site. May as well use a local site. Or, rather, have the GTM code being injected by a local extension to a random site that doesn't have GTM yet. Or maybe use a redirector extension to redirect the request for their GTM to yours, up to you.

After that, you just make a tag in GTM that would send a Universal Analytics pageview. GA4 decided not to bother with custom tasks, unfortunately, so UA only. Then you make a trigger on pageview. You assign the trigger to the tag. Don't forget to publish the workspace at least once for it to be testable. Then you preview. Preview is a CTA in GTM in top right corner, near the publish. Basically a neat GTM debugger. Enter the site where you have your GTM snippet deployed/injected. Make sure preview sees your tag firing on page load. That would mean you did the preparation correctly.

We're doing the Hint section here, by the way. Now you need to make a custom javascript variable in GTM, paste the code snippet as is in there. The reason why it wants the code in an anonymous function is because it will run it as a closure on it's own. So they kinda remove the need of the extra ()(). It's mostly done for people who don't know JS, so don't be surprised.

Ok, you've made the CJS var, now go to your tag, and set your customTag exactly as Simo shows in his article: [image]

Good, now publish your container, go to the site where you have it deployed, open the network tab and reload the page.

Inspect the calls to the BQ and Optimozg endpoints. Now what they ask is, I believe, why the original call that is meant to be sent by the tag is not being send. So if you remove the setting of the customTask, then publish and reload the page, you should see a request to the `collect` endpoint, which is the GA's endpoint for data tracking. If you re-add the customTask code, it will prevent the normal tag's functionality from execution, so no `collect` call.

What they want to hear from you is how to make the tag fire the original event alongside their optimozg and bq calls.

Most likely, the answer is pretty simple and elegant, but requires a lot of debugging to reach to. Reading Simo's article will help understanding the significance of setting various tasks.

Uh, ok, I didn't mean to really debug it, but it looks like I found the bug. It's in the `var f = tracker.get("sendHitTask")` It's being used to store the original sendHitTask function, but it never gets used. Why is that? Basically, you just need to call the function in the new sendHitTask function that you set in the last line. I'm not going to debug it in my GTM, but I'm pretty sure that's the issue. It's kinda begging to be found there.

Also, this is not quite a junior JS dev task. It's a senior tracking implementation task. Basically, about $110/hr in Canada and US. Junior JS devs are around $35/hr, I guess. They're just trying to save money, heh. I was thinking of hiring junior JS devs instead of tracking implementators too, but it's hard to teach how data analysis works in all the different tools.